# how to remove the space after the string in cell of csv file while importing

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

i have a file test.xml and i was trying to upload it but in 1st-row model_no has some empty space after the string which will give me that cell value as empty, how can I remove it while reading the data in code
img: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYQdH.png

```
        $errors = [];
        $importData = Excel::load($request->file('filename')->getRealPath(), function ($reader) use (&$errors) {
            $headerRow = $reader->first()->keys()->toArray();
            print_r($reader->toArray()); 

            if (!in_array("model_no", $headerRow)) { 
                $errors[] = 'Column model_no does not exists';
            } 
            if (!in_array("price", $headerRow)) { 
                $errors[] = 'Column price does not exists';
            }
            if (!in_array("qty", $headerRow)) { 
                $errors[] = 'Column qty does not exists';
            }
            return $errors;
        })->get()->toArray();
```

$reader->toArray() this will give me as result as

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [company_id] => 1
        [category] => BMS
        [product_type] => single
        [manufacturer] => 98
        [products] => 
        [model_no] => 
        [price] => 43200
        [units] => nos
        [max_discount] => 45
        [tax] => 18
        [hsn_code] => 998732
        [weight] => 1
        [qty] => 0
        [min_qty] => 0
        [enable_disable] => 1
        [warranty] => 0
    )
 );
```

composer.json file

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.4",
    "daltcore/lara-pdf-merger": "^2.0",
    "davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs": "^5.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "intervention/image": "^2.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^5.6",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0",
    "mpdf/mpdf": "^7.1",
    "ntwindia/ntwindia": "^1.0",
    "unisharp/laravel-filemanager": "~1.8"
},
"require-dev": {
    "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": [
        ]
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
}
```

Comment: So `model_no` gives you empty string instead of `abc      `?

Comment: yes, that's the main problem

Comment: What happens if you remove the extra trailing space? Does it happen for all rows? Are you looking at the correct excel file?

Comment: if i remove extra trailing spaces then it will get imported properly. it only happens for 1st row where it has space

Comment: Strange. It's hard to say anything this way. Can you show your composer.json and share the file via Google drive link?